# Different behavior of same regular expression in Python and Java

Tags: java, python, regex

Firstly, my apologies as I don't know regular expressions that well.

I am using a regular expression to match a string. I tested it in Python command line interface, but when I ran it in Java, it produced a different result.

Python execution:

```
re.search("[0-9]*[\\.[0-9]+]?[^0-9]*D\\([M|W]\\)\\s*US", "9.5 D(M) US");
```

gives the result as:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='9.5 D(M) US'>
```

But the Java code

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegexTest {
    private static final Pattern FALLBACK_MEN_SIZE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[\\.[0-9]+]?[^0-9]*D\\([M|W]\\)\\s*US");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strTest = "9.5 D(M) US";
    Matcher matcher = FALLBACK_MEN_SIZE_PATTERN.matcher(strTest);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

gives the output as:

5 D(M) US

I don't understand why it is behaving the different way.

Comment: Note that you can ditch the extra backslashes in Python with a "raw string* `r'[0-9]*[\.[0-9]+]?...'`, and that you can use `\d` for `[0-9]`.

Comment: Well, the regex definitely needs some adjustment. You put alternatives into a character class rather than in a group.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comment, will do that

Comment: @stribizhev can you please elaborate.

Comment: Also the pipe in `[M|W]` is a literal character to match...  have a look at e.g. https://regex101.com/r/kT9fD4/1

Comment: A basic difference b/w regex in Java and in Python is that in Java you need to escape a lot of characters.

Comment: @bhuwansahni: I posted my answer, I hope it is all clear now. I advise [Visual Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) to check Java regex internals for such difficult cases, and for PCRE/Python/JS regex, you can use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). And with properly written regular expressions, similar problems should not occur. Please check the character classes and alternation regex operator at [regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the pattern that will work the same in Java and Python:

```
"[0-9]*(?:\\.[0-9]+)?[^0-9]*D\\([MW]\\)\\s*US"
```

See [Python](https://ideone.com/vNF2j3) and [Java](https://ideone.com/3bRxJz) demos.

In Python, `[\\.[0-9]+]?` is read as 2 subpatterns: `[\.[0-9]+` (1 or more `.`s, `[`s, or digits) and `]?` (0 or 1 `]`). See how [your regex works in Python here](https://regex101.com/r/xI7zC7/1). Or, with more detalization with capturing groups, [here](https://regex101.com/r/xI7zC7/2).

In Java, it is read as one single character class (i.e. `[` and `]` inside are **ignored** as they cannot be parsed correctly by the regex engine, thus the whole subpattern standing for 0 or 1 `.`, a digit, or `+`) and since it is optional, it was not capturing anything (you can get a visual hint at [Visual Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/), type `123.+[]` as input and `[\.[0-9]+]?` as regex).

And a final touch: `[M|W]` stands for `M`, `|`, or `W`, while I think you meant `[MW]` = `M` or `W`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Python expert, so I can't tell you why it worked on Python, but in Java, your problem is the `[\\.[0-9]+]?` part. You probably meant it to be `(\\.[0-9]+)?`.

As it is, it's a list of characters inside a `[]` followed by a `?`. That is, this part of the expression only matches a single or zero character, so it cannot match the `.5` together.

Here is an illustration of the matching attempts:

[image: Graphical demonstration of matching in Java]

Now, if your pattern used `()` instead of `[]`, this would be the result:

[image]