# Inconsistency in Regex Match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[[!-~]]{6,32}$
```

This should match all strings (without white spaces) that contain at least 1 digit, 1 alphabetical character, and whose length is between 6 and 32. I'm almost positive that my regex is correct because it works perfectly [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/0sTqYcO41v). However, when I use `Regex.IsMatch` in C# it doesn't work.

```
bool isValidInput = Regex.IsMatch(myValue, myRegex) // I expect this to be true but it's false
```

Beside C#, I also noticed that some other testers don't like my regex either. Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/tT2vV5/1). What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is a pretty good site to test your regex stuff

Comment: Under which input it fails?

Comment: regexr.com didn't match my input. The input is provided in the two links I provided. The input I used is: abc3#de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This should match all strings (without white spaces) that contain at least 1 digit, 1 alphabetical character, and whose length is between 6 and 32 ...

`[[!-~]]` is the problem with your regular expression, a [**breakdown**](https://regex101.com/r/tT2vV5/2): ( right column )

Instead, I'm pretty sure you're looking for the following, `\S` matches non-whitespace characters.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\S{6,32}$
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is that `[[!-~]]` range is actually 2 subpatterns: `[[!-~]` character class and a literal `]`.

Change it to `[!-~]`:

[image]

So, use `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[!-~]{6,32}$`.

See [demo on REGEXSTORM that supports .NET regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3D.*%5Cd)(%3F%3D.*%5Ba-zA-Z%5D)%5B!-%7E%5D%7B6%2C32%7D%24&i=abc3%23de). While regex101.com is cool, you must always be very careful testing .NET regexes there. Some features are not supported (class subtraction, variable-width look-behind, Right-To-Left flag, etc.).

If you want to require the use of any Unicode letters, use `\p{L}`:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\p{L})[!-~]{6,32}$
```

The same issue with `[]` can be observed in Python vs. Java. But [this is a different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527195/different-behavior-of-same-regular-expression-in-python-and-java/30527643#30527643) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex seams to be the `[[!-~]]` part, try this instead, since you said:

> This should match all strings (without white spaces)

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\S{6,32}$
```